# Spark/Scala repeated creation of DataFrames using the same function on different data subsets

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My current code repeatedly creates new DataFrames (df_1, df_2, df_3) using the same function, but applied on different subsets of the original DataFrame df (e.g. where("category == 1')).

I would like to create a function that can automate the creation of these DataFrames.

In the following example, My DataFrame df has three columns: "category", "id", and "amount". Assume I have 10 categories. I want to summarise the value of the column 'category' as well as count the number of occurrences of 'category' based on different categories:

```
val df_1 = df.where("category == 1")
.groupBy("id")
.agg(sum(when(col("amount") > 0,(col("amount")))).alias("total_incoming_cat_1"),
count(when(col("amount") < 0, (col("amount")))).alias("total_outgoing_cat_1"))

val df_2 = df.where("category == 2")
.groupBy("id")
.agg(sum(when(col("amount") > 0,(col("amount")))).alias("total_incoming_cat_2"),
count(when(col("amount") < 0, (col("amount")))).alias("total_outgoing_cat_2"))

val df_3 = df.where("category == 3")
.groupBy("id")
.agg(sum(when(col("amount") > 0, (col("amount")))).alias("total_incoming_cat_3"),
count(when(col("amount") < 0, (col("amount")))).alias("total_outgoing_cat_3"))
```

I would like something like this:

```
def new_dfs(L:List, df:DataFrame): DataFrame={
  for l in L{
    val df_+l df.filter($amount == l)
    .groupBy("id")
    .agg(sum(when(col("amount") > 0, (col("amount")))).alias("total_incoming_cat_"+l),
    count(when(col("amount") < 0, (col("amount")))).alias("total_outgoing_cat_"+l))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it is not better to group by category and id

```
df
.groupBy("category","id")
.agg(sum(when(col("amount") > 0,(col("amount")))).alias("total_incoming_cat"),
count(when(col("amount") < 0, (col("amount")))).alias("total_outgoing_cat"))
```

Comment: No because I have more than 3 categories but only want to filter according to particular ones.

Comment: but you can do this also  :  df.filter(col("category").isin(Array("1","2","3")))
.groupBy("category","id")
.agg(sum(when(col("amount") > 0,(col("amount")))).alias("total_incoming_cat"),
count(when(col("amount") < 0, (col("amount")))).alias("total_outgoing_cat"))

Comment: Thanks, Francoceing. It's just this does not give me the individual datasets I want as an output. What I'm after is one row per id, with amounts (sum/count) by category columns. Your suggestion outputs the information I'm after but in a terrible format (loads of nulls as each category-id pair is mapped to every single category column).